# How to execute shell script from premake5.lua

Tags: lua, premake

I am trying to add a prebuild task in the premake5.lua file. Basically I want to change directory and execute a shell script. I searched and apparently I can use the function "prebuildcommands { "commands" }" as mentioned in the documentation.

What I would like to do is:

```
prebuildcommands { 
-- cd ..
-- cd ..
-- cd someDirectory
-- ./some script (execute the script)
-- come back to the original directory
}
```

Any ideas?
I already saw that os.execute can be used, but I don't know lua scripting very good.

Comment: `prebuildcommands` is to add command in the generated solution, whereas `os.execute` would execute when running premake... When the script should be launched? (which is the purpose of the script?)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, this just worked for me:

```
os.execute("cd ../../buildScripts && ./build.sh && cd ../original/directory")
```

If there are more elegant ways, for example with functions, please post them.

Comment: `os.execute` creates its own subprocess, which has its own current directory not affecting the current directory of the parent process.  So, you may remove `&& cd ../original/directory`